# Swift detect location name from dict

Tags: swift

I have dict of locations with coordinates and names in my dictionary. I'm using user location to detect if user is on one of the locations in my dict. Dictionary looks like this `var loc:[String: [Double]] = ["The Empire State Building":[40.748440, -73.985672]]`.

What I want to do is detect if user is at one of locations. Is there a faster way then circle through whole dict and detect the one that has smallest deviation from actual lat and long in dict?

Comment: Please show how the dictionary is defined. It looks like `[String:[Double]]`, is it correct?

Comment: No, it's `[String:[Double, Double]]`, for example `["The Empire State Building":[40.748440, -73.985672]]`

Comment: There's nothing like this `[String:[Double, Double]]` in Swift

Comment: It's an array in dict, the data structure doesn't matter yet. The question is is there a better way then to circle through whole dict? I could also have 3 arrays. First one with names, second one with lat and third with long

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the closest place you'll need to evaluate every element in your list. So there is not a faster way then looping over the whole list of elements.

Unless you manage to keep you places sorted (or indexed), but I don't know if this is possible in your scenario.